# Play framework Websocket

Tags: websocket, playframework-2.4

I am trying to implement real time notification for a web application I an currently working on.
The problem is the connection is getting closed just after few seconds.Can It be possible to keep connection ideal.If not please suggest me the alternative to implement this.

Comment: Do you have this problem in local or on a server ? is the request proxyed by something ?

Comment: @ Julien Lafont this is the same in local or server. seems play keep this restriction. In play's sample app too they are running a scheduler to keep all sockets alive.